# Ошибка в построении модели линейной регрессии (sklearn). Огромная погрешность

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, sklearn

Прохожу соревнование [www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques](http://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques)

Получившаяся предиктивная модель выдает огромную ошибку:

```
mse 5811162076.48
sqrt(mse) 76230.98
avg_error 57070.42
```

Знатоки, подскажите, как исправить\улучшить результат. Пробовал реализовать модель с помощью данного решения([www.kaggle.com/vipin20/house-prices-eda-feature-engineering-top-10](http://www.kaggle.com/vipin20/house-prices-eda-feature-engineering-top-10)). Код выложил на GITHUB (https://github.com/Sergey-Kit/All/blob/c5f93237ab55079740ebedb35d47233d25e1c3c0/Prediction%20of%20House%20Prices.ipynb)

Comment: А почему вы сравниваете результат с некоей `'sample_submission.csv'`, там вообще что за данные то, почему вы считаете их эталонными? Вам надо для начала откладывать часть данных на `train` и тестировать ваши предсказания по этой отложенной части. То, что ваши предсказания могут оказаться не слишком похожими на чьи-то ещё предсказания - это не показатель. Ну и да, линейная регрессия в случае наличия категориальных данных - не лучший вариант, понятное дело. Особенно если вы не подготовили их правильно (я весь код не смотрел, не знаю, как вы категориальные фичи подготовили).

Comment: А так то да, судя по гигантским коэффициентам, LR какую-то ботву выдала. Хотите простых моделей - используйте регуляризацию, т.е. не просто LR, а `Ridge`, `Lasso` или `ElasticNet`. Не факт, что у них обойдётся без проблем, но надо пробовать. А так лучше всё-таки использовать модели, которые понимают в категориальных фичах - `RandomForest`, `LightGBM`, `CatBoost`. Самому правильно обойтись с категориальными фичами, чтобы взлетела линейная модель, бывает не так уж и просто.

Comment: Ради интереса попробовал, `RF` даёт `RMSE = 11193`, что гораздо лучше, чем `76230`, но всё-равно многовато. Пока не смог ничего интересного больше нарыть, надо разбираться детально. Но учтите, что в лидерборде там давно всякие читеры, которые гнались специально за скором, подогнать скор под лидерборд не вопрос, нулевая погрешность скорее всего означает именно такую подгонку, а не что у них модели очень хорошие.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! Попробую модель RF, по вашему совету.

Comment: Главное, правильно метрику считайте, как я в ответе написал. Но вообще там ещё надо анализировать и работать с фичами дальше, если хотите реально хорошие результаты получить :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснилось, надо было всего лишь почитать раздел [Evaluation](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/overview/evaluation)

> **Metric**
>
> Submissions are evaluated on Root-Mean-Squared-Error (RMSE) between
> the **logarithm** of the predicted value and the **logarithm** of the
> observed sales price. (Taking logs means that errors in predicting
> expensive houses and cheap houses will affect the result equally.)

Правим код:

```
mse = np.mean((np.log(y_test_verification['SalePrice'])-np.log(y_pred))**2)
```

Получаем метрики не такие уже страшные:

```
mse 0.19601661402442377
sqrt(mse) 0.44273763565392066
```

А если взять модель посложнее, которая лучше работает с категориальными переменными, хотя бы даже старый добрый `Random Forest`, то будет ещё лучше:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(mean_squared_error(np.log(y_test_verification['SalePrice']), np.log(rf.predict(X_test)))**0.5)

# 0.3586312743499053
```

Хотя, повторю свой комментарий - непонятно, что там в `'sample_submission.csv'`, насколько это правильные предсказания, чтобы на них ориентироваться. На `X_train, y_train` при проверке `RF` вообще отличный скор обучения показывает 0.05, например.